# My icons constantly appear and disappear on desktop area

Tags: icons, desktop-icons

I'm having a problem on Ubuntu the desktop icons stay appearing and disappearing constantly.
Another thing that happens when I right-click on the desktop I can't click on the options that appear.
can anybody help me?